# outline view in vscode not available

Tags: visual-studio-code, outline-view

Started using vscode 1.64.2 on windows 10 occasionally for a while.

Just now, when I tried to work with workspace on local windows 10 machine, the outline view is missing, and no where I can find it or open.

I've moved the outline view to the right size bar when working with workspace on a remote linux host a while ago; and it still works fine.

If I open the two workspaces side-by-side, the outline view is there in the vscode for the remote workspace; it's just not available for local workspace.

How can I get the outline view for local workspace?

Comment: I downloaded vscode 1.68.1 to a separate folder than vscode 1.64.2, now I can open 1.68.1 to get the outline view on local workspace. Still not able to get that with 1.64.2, it's not available in the Open View ... menu button, meaning it's opened and hidden?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Visual Studio Code Docs (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown) says the feature still exists.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem.
Select "View" from the Main Menu in VSCode, then "Open view..." and then you can find the Outline view.

Comment: This must be marked as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 1.72.2. I found leaving the explorer window open for a while fixed the issue. I believe it is just a slow backend process that doesn't notify the user it is running.